# Meteor Fixtures

Tags: meteor, collections, fixtures

I have been working with this problem for 1 hour already and I cannot be any more frustrated than this.

#### lib/categories_colection.js

```
Categories = new Mongo.Collection('categories');
```

#### server/fixtures.js

```
if (Categories.find().count === 0) {
  var categories = [
    {
      category: 'Medicine',
    },
    {
      category: 'Agriculture',
    },
    {
      category: 'Food',
    },
    {
      category: 'Industrial',
    },
    {
      category: 'Agriculture',
    },
  ];

  _.each(categories, function (category) {
    var id;
    id = Categories.insert({
      category: category.category,
      sub: []
    });
  });
};
```

Am I doing something wrong?

It's pretty much straight forward.. But it seems its not working..

**Update**: When I start the server in `localhost:3000/` no collection of 'categories' is being made, and fixtures is not adding.

Other fixtures such as `Meteor.users` is working though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want:

```
if (Categories.find().count() === 0) {
```

instead of:

```
if (Categories.find().count === 0) {
```

Comment: Hahaha.. Dumbest mistake ever. I've been coding for 8 hours straight... I should take a break. Thanks @Michael Mason